# Mongoose on CentOS 7.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, centos

I have a CentOS 7.1 with Nodejs v0.12.4

when I try to install mongoose `npm install mongoose`  I get this error:

```
>kerberos@0.0.12 install /home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
npm WARN installMany nopt was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany npmlog was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany semver was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar-pack was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany mkdirp was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany rc was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany rimraf was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
\
> bson-ext@0.1.7 install /home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext
> (node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build) || (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.node" "--module_name=bson" "--module_path=/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /home/node/www/broker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.node --module_name=bson --module_path=/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /home/node/www/broker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.node --module_name=bson --module_path=/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release' (1)
make: Entering directory `/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/node/www/broker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
mongoose@4.0.3 node_modules/mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── muri@1.0.0
├── hooks-fixed@1.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── async@0.9.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── mquery@1.5.1 (debug@0.7.4, bluebird@2.9.9)
├── mongodb@2.0.30 (readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.1.26)
└── bson@0.3.2 (bson-ext@0.1.7)
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a C++ compiler (among other things).

Comment: worked. if you wanna answer "sudo yum install gcc-c++" I am gonna accept it

Comment: That didn't solve the warnings presumably so I would assume some things are still not working as intended but I'm glad that solved the error.